# disabled inputs and selects misagligned when creating image via html2canvas

Tags: javascript, css, uikit, html2canvas

I have a series of labels and disabled inputs.  When I create an image with `html2canvas`, the inputs are misaligned.

Here is the web page source:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.19/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .ukc-input-disabled {
            cursor: default;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .ukc-input-disabled:not([type="checkbox"]) {
            border: 0 none !important;
            background-color: transparent !important;
            background-image: none !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
        }
        .ukc-input-disabled.uk-checkbox {
            background-color: #f8f8f8 !important;
        }
        .ukc-input-disabled.uk-checkbox:checked {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%2214%22%20height%3D%2211%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2011%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cpolygon%20fill%3D%22%23999%22%20points%3D%2212%201%205%207.5%202%205%201%205.5%205%2010%2013%201.5%22%20%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A");
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function () {
            html2canvas(document.getElementById('theform'), {}).then(function (canvas) {
                var img = jQuery('<img>');
                img.attr("src", canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
                jQuery('body').append(img); //todo
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="theform">
    <div class="uk-display-inline-block uk-text-nowrap uk-margin uk-margin-left@s uk-margin-right">
        <label class="uk-text-bold" for="rga_type_select"><span>Type</span>:</label>
        <select name="rga_type" id="rga_type_select" class="uk-select uk-width-small ukc-border ukc-input-disabled">
            <option value="C">Credit</option>
            <option value="E" selected>Rent payment</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-display-inline-block uk-text-nowrap uk-margin uk-margin-left uk-margin-right">
        <label for="rga_cpo_textinput" class="uk-text-bold">CPO:</label>
        <input name="rga_cpo" id="rga_cpo_textinput" class="uk-input uk-width-small ukc-border ukc-input-disabled" value="test123">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-display-inline-block uk-text-nowrap uk-margin uk-margin-left uk-margin-right">
        <label class="uk-text-bold" for="rga_reason_select"><span>Reason</span>:</label>
        <select name="rga_reason" id="rga_reason_select" class="uk-select uk-width-auto ukc-border ukc-input-disabled">
            <option value="B">Lorem Ipsum</option>
            <option value="C" selected>Hello there</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-display-inline-block uk-text-nowrap uk-margin uk-margin-left uk-margin-right">
        <label class="uk-text-bold" for="rga_decline_qty_checkbox">Return declined quantity</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rga_decline_qty" id="rga_decline_qty_checkbox" class="uk-checkbox ukc-input-disabled">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin-top">
        <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" style="display: none;">Select Items</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It displays as:
[image: displays as]

Notice that, in the image, the disabled inputs are misaligned.

Comment: html2canvas can tamper with your css. One solution is to add a css class name to your selects before you call the html2canvas method (and remove it in the finally). This class could adjust the line-height of your selects; however the user will see the change while the method runs. The other solution is to show conditionnally span elements with the selection, so html2canvas prints these instead of the selects. Maybe it would help if you showed your html2canvas implementation.